# Defining onesignal_app_id outside js

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, react-native, onesignal

I am trying to use onesignal for my android app. Currently, this is working, but I have this line in my file app.js:

```
OneSignal.init('xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx');
```

where all the xxxx represents my onesignal_app_id. This is what is recommended in [OneSignal doc](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk), but I am not familiar with app creation, and my question is: Does this mean that if someone unzip the apk, he can get my onesignal_app_id?

I was using an older buildTool (23.0.2) before, allowing me to write the onesignal_app_id in the gradle (as can be seen [here](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/blob/732491fece1fa92946ca6dacf173af28a2b2e618/README.md)), and it felt safer. But I had to update some dependencies, and I need to use buildTools 28, and the previous method does not work anymore.

So my question is: can I write the app_id safely in my code? If not, how to put it in a safe place?

Thanks a lot,
djazouli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not dangerous to reveal your onesignal-app-id, as can be read [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/security#section-what-happens-if-a-bad-actor-gains-access-to-my-app_id-)